# React componentWillUpdate runs every second and condition not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

I have a React component with `componentWillUpdate` in this lifecycle method I call an action, the action has a console.log in it.

I have Two questions:

1. why is the `componentWillUpdate` runs every second?
2. why the if in the `componentWillUpdate` is not working?
   shouldn't it run only when the props are not the same?

this is the component code:

** **updated** **

```
     import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchCourses } from "../../actions";

class Courses extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCourses();
  }

  componentWillUpdate(prevProps) {

    if (this.props.courses !== prevProps.courses) {
      console.log('prevProps.courses ', prevProps.courses);
      console.log('this.props.courses ', this.props.courses);
      this.props.fetchCourses();
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log('this.props.payload.courses ', this.props.courses);
    const courses = this.props.courses.map(course => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{course.coursename}</td>

          <td>{course.coursetype ? "yes" : "no"}</td>

          <td>{course.courseweeklyhours}</td>

          <td>
            <button>הסר</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        Courses
        {courses}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  // console.log('state ', state);

  return {
    courses: state.courses
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchCourses }
)(Courses);
```

Courses returns an array

[image]

Comment: what does `courses` contains ?

Comment: This is not the entire component. There's no componentDidMount. If this is really about componentDidMount and not componentWillUpdate, the problem is in parent component, which isn't shown either. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: @estus -  Sorry, pasted wrong code . Now fixed

Comment: @SagarJajoriya added the courses code

Comment: @DavSev I see. How do you know that componentDidMount runs multiple times? If it really does, the problem is in parent component, as I mentioned.

Comment: @estus The question is actually regarding componentWillUpdate.. The title was wrong initially

Comment: The problem is with this condition `this.props.courses !== prevProps.courses` because it will return true always because you cannot check the equality of two arrays like that, so that's why the `this.props.fetchCourses()` called everytime in your `componentWillUpdate` method.

Comment: @SagarJajoriya how do you suggest fixing this condition?
I id do `===` the data is not loaded after props change

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-deep-equal

Comment: why do you want to re-fetch on every change of courses?

Comment: @DavSev You probably need to revise the way you update `courses` outside the component. If it's `Courses` that is responsible for fetching courses, why would it check props? It already 'knows' whether a fetch was called or not.

Comment: Also, using `componentWillUpdate` to make a side-effect isn't a good practice. You should do it in `componentDidUpdate`. `componentWillUpdate` from the docs: "Note that you cannot call this.setState() here; nor should you do anything else (e.g. dispatch a Redux action) that would trigger an update to a React component before UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate() returns.". Another thing, `componentWillUpdate` will be deprecated in future versions and is signed as "UNSAFE"

Comment: @MatanBobi I changed to componentDidUpdate but now the component dosent run on updates at all

Comment: @JiN yes, update the component on every course update.

Comment: What you want to check with this condition `this.props.courses !== prevProps.courses`, the length of the prev and new courses OR the elements of both prev and new courses ?

Comment: did iy a few minutes ago, but the lifecycle dosent run after update

Comment: ` componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    console.log('prevProps.courses length', prevProps.courses.length);
    console.log('this.props.courses length', this.props.courses.length);
    if (this.props.courses.length !== prevProps.courses.length) {
      console.log('prevProps.courses length', prevProps.courses.length);
      console.log('this.props.courses length', this.props.courses.length);
      this.props.fetchCourses();
    }
  }`

the console works only on on page load

Comment: @DavSev could u explain why it is that u want to call fetchCourses on every update of courses.. How are the values of courses changed?

Comment: @JiN how do you use fast-deep-equal in react? after installing in npm you call `import equal from "fast-deep-equal";`?

Comment: import equal from "fast-deep-equal";

if (!equal(his.props.courses, prevProps.courses)) {
// your code
}

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
const arr2 = [1,2,3,4]

arr1 == arr2 // answer is false
```

So `arr1 !== arr2` means true. So the code block will run. Inside there, you call action creator. Now the store will be updated. Now again it will check for the condition inside the componentWillUpdate(). Yep. again `arr1 !== arr2` which means true. so again it will run. again it will call action creator. the same thing happens infinite time. The problem is with your condition.

1) Every time when you update the store componentWillUpdate() execute. Inside there, You have forever true condition. In that, inside the 'if structure' you call action creator again. so it will update store again. Therefor componentWillUpdate() execute again. Now because of forever true condition 'if structure' will run again. will run again and again until you kill the server.